# ASP.NET Core 6 UseDefaultFiles except for a certain path pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to serve a SPA Web app and a GraphQL test UI on the same endpoint.

The idea is that if a request comes in under `http://<host>:<port>/graphql/`, the test UI should be served (this is set up by the `MapGraphQL` call).

Everything else should be handled by `UseStaticFiles` and `UseDefaultFiles`.

However, it seems that no matter the order I am setting up the calls, `UseDefaultFiles` kicks in.

Here's a rough order of the calls:

```cs
app.UseCors( ... );
app.UseRouting();
app.UseDefaultFiles( new DefaultFilesOptions
{
     RequestPath = "",
     FileProvider = fileProvider
} );

app.UseStaticFiles( staticFileOptions );

app.UseEndpoints( builder =>
{
    endpoints.MapGraphQL();
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    builder.MapFallbackToFile( "/index.html", new StaticFileOptions
    {
        RequestPath = "",
        FileProvider = fileProvider
    } );
} );
```

Loading `http://<host>:<port>/graphql/` in the browser always loads the `index.html` of the SPA.

Comment: Wich package did you use to manage GraphQL integration? Did you tried to specify `"/graphql"` path in `MapGraphQL` method?